# HTTPS client could not get authorized by the server

Tags: c, linux, http, ssl, https

I am writing a C code on Linux platform(Fedora) for HTTPS client. The client can successfully create TCP connection and SSL connection. It could get the certificate from the server but when I send a HTTP GET request on the SSL socket the server sends "Authorization Exception".

When I send the GET request from a web browser (https://hostname:port/path) I get the prompt for entering username/password and after entering the credentials(same credentials as being entered in my HTTPS client application), correct response is received from the server.

I am afraid if I am making a wrong HTTP "request" string.

Below is the code snippet:

```
  char* base64EncodeOutput, *text="user1:pass"; 

  // Server expects credentials in base64encoding
  Base64Encode(text, strlen(text), &base64EncodeOutput);
  printf("Output (base64): %s\n", base64EncodeOutput);

  char request[800];
  sprintf(request,"GET /abc_webapi_version/HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                   "Authorization: Basic %s\r\n"
                   "Accept: application/xml\r\n"
                   "Host: 10.0.10.10:8080\r\n"
                   "User-Agent: WebAPI/HTTP-client\r\n"
                   "\r\n"
                   ,base64EncodeOutput);
  int rety=0;
  rety = SSL_write(ssl, (const void *)request, strlen(request));
  printf("Ret SSL_Write %d\n",rety);

  char *response;
  response = (char *)malloc(100*sizeof(char));
  rety = SSL_read(ssl, (void *)respnonse, 100);
  printf("Bytes read %d\n", rety);
  printf("Data= %s\n", response);

  SSL_free(ssl);
  close(server);
```

Please help me and let me know if I am making a correct HTTP get request or if there is anything else which is causing the problem.

Comment: Shouldn't the encoded username/password be passed in as a header?

Comment: Yes it has been passed. The variable name is base64EncodeOutput.

Comment: The problem is related to TLS/SSL. The server supports TLSv1.0. I used openssl s_client command to test if the openssl connection establishes.The output is
---
No client certificate CA names sent
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    ------ SOME FIELDS ---------------
    Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
---
read:errno=0

Comment: The cause of the problem is weak ephemeral key used by the server. Somehow my application rejects the weak key. If anyone can suggest how to overcome this problem, then please reply.